# Game Center leaderboards won't show up

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

Okay, I've been trying to display the Game Center leaderboards in my **Cocos2d** iPhone game.
I have progressed and I got this piece of code:

```
- (void) showLeaderboard {
tempVC=[[UIViewController alloc] init];

GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (leaderboardController != nil)
{
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:tempVC.view];
    [tempVC presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated: YES];
}
```

}

When I run that in the simulator, I see it becomes portrait mode, so I know something happened. BUT nothing appears. No leaderboards come out. What is wrong?

- My application is already linked with the iTunes thingy.
- I am authenticated at the beginning of the game sucessfully.
- I already submitted scores (with a nice thing called GameKitHelper)

Comment: i tried your codes on my app and it works fine.. I'm not sure wads wrong with yours.. are there any warnings??

Answer (score 2):

Go to the AppDelegate.m and change:

```
[window addSubview: viewController.view];
to
window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

then call it

```
GameKitHelper* gkHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper];
[gkHelper showLeaderboard];
```

This works on cocos2d 1.0.0 RC1